# Statistical significance in scatterplot in R

Tags: r

I have a large scatterplot, with about 100,000 (x,y) points. The x coordinate is the set of numbers from (1 to ~100,000) - in other words, no 2 points have the same x-coordinate. The y is mostly constant (around 50-70 in value), but there are key "regions" where the y value spikes to ~120 or drops to ~20. How would I statistically differentiate these regions?

What R functions would be most appropriate?

Comment: This is a statistical question, not a programming one. Try `stats.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Questions here are meant to be primarly on issues with coding in R. It would help to show us what you tried, and where you're having a problem. Your question sounds more like one dealing with statistics than R, and would be better on stats.stackexchange.com. That said, it's still not a very good question for stats.stackexchange.com, either. It gives us no idea of what you tried.

Comment: @Chris Well I'll ask on `stats.stackexchange.com`, but nevertheless, it is not about trying something - mostly advice from a qualifed statistician to a high school student about what would be the correct method to employ

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistical methods for differentiating portions of a plot; it's a better fit for crossvalidated.com.

Answer (score 1):

What is your null hypothesis?  or what exactly are you trying to test/show?

One possibility (once you have figured out the hypothesis to test/assumptions under the null) is to use the methods in:

> ```
>  Buja, A., Cook, D. Hofmann, H., Lawrence, M. Lee, E.-K., Swayne,
>  D.F and Wickham, H. (2009) Statistical Inference for exploratory
>  data analysis and model diagnostics Phil. Trans. R. Soc. A 2009
>  367, 4361-4383 doi: 10.1098/rsta.2009.0120
> ```

The `vis.test` function (and related functions) in the TeachingDemos package for R helps with one implementation of the above methods.